# Adicionar valores no campo apertando a tecla 'enter' e zerar esses valores com botão 'reset' em Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, select, option

E aí blz? Como posso adicionar valores no campo apertando a tecla 'enter' ao invés de clicar no botão 'adicionar' e como zerar esses mesmos valores dentro do 'select' com botão 'reset' com o Javascript?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Analisador de Números</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header><h1>Verificador de Número</h1></header>
    <section>
        <label for="numero">Digite um número (de 1 a 100): </label><input type="number" id="numero"> <input type="button" id="numero" value="adicionar" onclick="adicionar()">
        <select name="campo" id="campo" size="10"></select>
        <br>
        <button onclick="verificar()">Verificar</button>
        <div id="result">Aguardando valores...</div>
        <button onclick="zerar()">Zerar</button>
    </section>



    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <footer><p>&#169;CursoemVideo</p></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
let numero = document.querySelector('input#numero')
let campo = document.querySelector('select#campo')
let valores = []
let result = document.querySelector('div#result')
let soma = 0
let media = 0

function adicionar() {
    if(numero.value.length == 0) {
        alert('Digite valores abaixo')
    }else if(numero.value < 1 || numero.value > 100) {
        alert('Digite um número entre 1 e 100')
    }else {
        if(valores.indexOf(Number(numero.value)) != -1) {
            alert('Esse número já foi adicionado')
        }else {
            valores.push(Number(numero.value))
            let item = document.createElement('option')
            item.text = `Número ${Number(numero.value)} adicionado.`
            campo.appendChild(item)
            soma += Number(numero.value)
            media = parseFloat(soma / valores.length).toFixed(2)
            numero.value = ''
            numero.focus()
        }
    }
}

function verificar() {
    let maior = valores[0] 
    let menor = valores[0]
    let cont = 0
    while(cont < valores.length) {
        if(valores[cont] > maior) {
            maior = valores[cont]
        }else if(valores[cont] < menor) {
            menor = valores[cont] 
        }
        cont++
    }

    if(valores.length == 0) {
        alert('Digite valores acima')
    }else {
        let qtd = valores.length
        result.innerHTML =`<p>Você digitou ${qtd} números</p>`
        result.innerHTML +=`<p>A soma dos números deu ${soma}</p>`
        result.innerHTML += `<p>A média dos números deu ${media}</p>`
        result.innerHTML += `<p>O maior número é ${maior}</p>`
        result.innerHTML += `<p>O menor número é ${menor}</p>`
    }
}

function zerar() {
    valores.item = ''
    result.innerHTML = ''
}
```

CSS:

```
*{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

header {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

body {
    background-color: rgb(72, 72, 219);
}

section {
    max-width: 600px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

section .num {
    text-align: center;
}

section select {
    width: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

section #result {
    margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
}

section #result {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

footer {
    text-align: center;
    font-style: italic;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, para zerar o 'select', você estava fazendo certo mas usou a variável errada. Deveria ser:

```
function zerar() {
    valores.item = ''
    campo.innerHTML = ''
}
```

Para chamar a função verificar com o enter, você pode usar a função [keyCode](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_keycode.asp) e comparar com a da tecla enter, que é 13

```
window.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
        verificar()
    }
})
```

Comment: E aí André, era exatamente isso, deu certo aqui, muito obrigado!

Comment: Show Glebson, feliz em ajudar :)